# Django, upgrading to 1.9

Tags: django, django-urls

I evolve my Django version to 1.9 (before I had the 1.6 or 1.7), so I modify many obseltes things...

But I have a problem with theses lines in my urls.py :

```
import django
import main_app 
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from main_app.views import *
from main_app.views import password_reset_confirm
... # many urls
url(r'^authentification/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login),
url(r'^forget/send/$', django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done),
url(r'^password/$', django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset),
url(r'^password_forget/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', main_app.views.password_reset_confirm),
url(r'^password-init/$', django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete),
```

I have this error when I write "python manage.py runserver" :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f5bcf01af50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in  import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/yb/web/carzuip/carzuip/urls.py", line 55, in <module>
url(r'^authentification/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login),
NameError: name 'django' is not defined
```

I don't understand why I have a problem just with those 5 urls ??!

Thank's

Comment: Are you importing django?...

Comment: Heu logicaly yes, I update my post for you can see my import

Answer (score 4):

That code *doesn't* show you importing `django`: it shows you importing elements underneath it, but never the name itself. It is a fundamental principle of Python that you must import or define every name you use. In your case, `import django` at the top would work, although note you would then have another problem when the code gets to the password_reset URL since that is referenced from `main_app` which you again haven't imported.

Comment: You don't `import django` in urls.py, there is a larger issue here.

Comment: the very first line is ``import django``

Comment: @allo which the OP added after my answer.

Comment: @GordonsBeard you do if that's how you're referencing the views you're using. I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new project with `django-admin startproject` and copy over the needed settings / copy over manage.py and wsgi.py.

Some releases had breaking changes, i.e. on how the wsgi module imports certain django stuff. Most projects can easy be recreated and you have the newest django defaults in the files.

It's of course just a guess, but worth trying. If you're using a virtualenv, you may need to recreate some things inside, when your python was upgraded / you moved the virtualenv. Such stuff can be quite annoying sometimes.

Comment: I already create a new project with django-admin startproject ^^

Comment: Did you play a bit with ``./manage.py shell``? Install ``ipython`` before doing so, then you can do stuff like ``django?`` (help text) and ``django??`` (help + source)

Comment: Yes I already play with the shell, and it's works correctly ^^..  I never installed ipython, what is this technology ?

Comment: ipython is just a wrapper of the interactive python to add some coloring, autocompletion and these help functions with the question marks (which work on all objects)

Comment: Thank you , I will see that !

Answer (score 2):

Resolved !

Euh I think...

Just I add these lines :

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login 
from django.contrib import auth
```

And it's works !

It's normal hein ?

Comment: Indeed, in your original code you did not import ``django.contrib.auth.views.login``. Try this in a python shell: ``print django.foo`` and you get ``NameError: name 'django' is not defined``

Comment: By the way, to avoid imports (and maybe circular imports) you can specify views as string, i.e. ``url(r'^authentification/$', "django.contrib.auth.views.login")``. I guess you will get more clear error messages then, too. Or, like you're doing now, import the function and not the whole module.

Comment: The specification of views as strings has been deprecated and will be gone in 1.10.